# How to get each month data count of the year in laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 8 and i want to get data of ***each month of the year***. For example

```
month1 => 12
month2 => 14 so on ...
```

I have code

```
 $invoices = Auth::user()->invoices()
        ->select(DB::raw('YEAR(invoice_date) year'), DB::raw('MONTH(invoice_date) month'), DB::raw('count(id) as `data`'))
        ->groupBy('year','month')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

it return following,

```
 array:2 [▼
1 => array:3 [▼
"year" => 2021
"month" => 1
"data" => 6
]
2 => array:3 [▼
"year" => 2021
"month" => 2
"data" => 4
```

]]

but **i have record in database 20**. mean for ***month 1 record are 12*** and for ***month 2 record are 8*** but i get different.
Kindly help me where is i am wrong.
Table structure is
[image]

Comment: could you add the table structure and model definition?

Comment: I have updated my question please have a look. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The code seems good. Add please `DB::enableQueryLog();` before and `Log::info(var_export(DB::getQueryLog(), true));` after the code. Than you can find sql query in the logs, add it to post

Comment: Nothing exist related to this in log

Comment: it's not true. This code logs all sql queries starts from `DB::enableQueryLog();`

Comment: Where queries exist? in storage/logs folder?

Comment: yes. The default file is storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: [2020-12-17 08:07:52] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = nheathcote@example.org and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = nheathcote@example.org and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1) at /var/www/html/ereciept/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:678)

Comment: nope, try to search sql queries with table `invoices` at the end of the file, and also do not add it to comment, edit ur post